# Hide to Show some information jQuery using Radio Button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to show different information based on radio buttons using jQuery.

When I select any payment processor then I want to show related payment method information on the right side.

So, when I select any button then show the information related to that payment processor, and at the same time hide information related to the other payment processors.

This is my HTML Form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php base_url(); ?>confirm_order" method="post">
    <fieldset>

        <div class="span4">
<!-- Left Side -->
            <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="paypal">Paypal<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="cart">Visa, Master Card, etc<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="cash_on_delevary">Cash on Delivery
<!-- End Left Side -->
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <!-- Right Side -->
            <div class="control-group" id="paypal">
                <label class="control-label" >Paypal Payment</label>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group" id="Cart">
                <label class="control-label" >Cart</label>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group" id="cash_on_delevary">
                <label class="control-label" >Cash on Delevary</label>
            </div>
            <!-- end Right Side -->
        </div>

        <input type="submit" name="Continue" class="btn btn-orange pull-right">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

What can I do?

Comment: you can use `$('#elementId').show()` and `$('#elementId').hide()`. you can find many examples on stackOverflow on this topic.

Comment: i didnt understand it fully!

Comment: If you want to switch between different radio buttons they have to have the same `name` (use their `id` to check selections).

Answer (score 4):

This will work:

```
$("input[type='radio']").change(function() {
    $(".control-group").hide();
    $("#" + this.name).show();
});
```

Comment: there is the `:radio` selector which could be used: http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/  of course this change nothing and your answer is good

Comment: @roasted: using the `:radio` selector prevents jQuery passing the selector to the `document.querySelectorAll()` (if present), which actively degrades performance. Negligibly, perhaps; but still a degradation.

Comment: @DavidThomas i think he meant `input:radio` wich wont change any performance(?) Not sure.

Comment: @Karl, from the [API](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/): "[because] `:radio` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:radio` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. For better performance in modern browsers, use `[type="radio"]` instead."

Comment: @DavidThomas Thank you for the info, didnt know. Which site did you take that?

Comment: From the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/), specifically the entry for the [`:radio` selector](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/) (incidentally, there is a link in the previous comment linking to that page).

Answer (score 1):

If you want radiobutton to work, you need to assign them the same name, else when you select 1, the others wont deselect.

What you should do is to assign a data on element to know wich section they show :

```
<input type="radio" data-for='paypal' checked="checked" name="payment">Paypal<br/>
<input type="radio" data-for='Cart' name="payment">Visa, Master etc<br/>
<input type="radio" data-for='cash_on_delevary' name="payment">Cash on Delevary
```

And then You bind the change event :

```
$("input[name=payment]").change(function() {
    $(".control-group").hide();
    $("#" + $(this).data("for")).show();
});
```

But to hide every section at start, you need to add this :

```
$(".control-group").hide();
$("input[name=payment]:checked").trigger('change')
```

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/a9Fvn/